# no me funciona la paginacion con angular

Tags: angular, paginación

el backend está hecho en nodejs y lo he probado con postman funciona pero en el front end no me va la paginación al hacer click por primera vez en la paginacion se recarga la pagina.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
      console.log(params);
      var page = +params['page'];
      console.log(page);
      if(!page || page == null  || page == undefined)
      {
        page = 1;
        this.prev_page = 1;
        console.log(this.prev_page);
        this.next_page = 2;
      }
      console.log(page);
      this.getBooks(page);
    });


    this.loadUser();
  }

  loadUser()
  {

    this.identity = this.userservice.getIdentity();
  //  console.log(this.identity);
    this.token = this.userservice.getToken();
  }

  getBooks(page)
  {
      //  console.log('error');
    this.bookservice.getBooks(page).subscribe(
      response =>
      {

        if(response.books)
        {
          this.books = response.books;
          console.log(this.books);

          // navegacion de paginación
          this.totalPages = response.totalPages;
          console.log(this.totalPages);

          var number_pages = [];
          for(var i = 1; i <= this.totalPages; i++)
          {
            number_pages.push(i);
          }
          this.number_pages = number_pages;

          if(page >=2)
          {
            this.prev_page = page-1;
          }
          else
          {
            this.prev_page = 1;
          }
          if(page < this.totalPages)
          {
            this.next_page = page+1;
          }
          else
          {
            this.next_page = this.totalPages;
          }

        }
        else
        {
         this.router.navigate(['inicio']);
         console.log('error');
        }
      },
      error =>
      {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

En el metodo ngOnInit() algo está mal pero la consola no me muestra error.

list-books.html

```
<div class="col-lag-12">


  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let book of books">
    <h4>
      <a [routerLink]="['/inicio']">
        {{book.title}}
      </a>
    </h4>
    <p>{{book.description}}</p>
    <p>{{book.author}}</p>
    <p>{{book.stock}}</p>
    <p>{{book.price}}</p>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="pagination">
   <li class="page-item">
     <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/books', prev_page]">&laquo;</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let num of number_pages">
      <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/books', num]" href="">{{ num }}</a>
   </li>

   <li class="page-item">
     <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/books', next_page]">&raquo;</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Creo que ya sé por que me falla la paginacion en el archivo de rutas del proyecto me carga la pagina que muestra los libros en`{ path: '**', component: ListBooksComponent },`

no por la ruta del componente   `{ path: 'list-books/:page', component: ListBooksComponent },`

pero no sé por que no me carga la ruta...

Comment: el error está en   ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
      
      var page = +params['page']; la variable page es nan no number por eso el metodo getBooks no recibe la pagina pero no se como solucionarlo

Answer (score 0):

Tus metodos que calculan el `this.prev_page` y `this.next_page` tienen que estar dentro de `ngOnChanges(){}` para que actualice la data.

Tambien podrias hacer esta validación.

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params=>{
  let page:number = +params.get('page');
  if (!page) {       
    page = 1;
  }
  this.getBooks(page); 
})
```

Comment: no me funciona el codigo si uso el metodo onChanges en lugar de OnInit no me carga el contenido y el codigo de dentro del onchanges si lo uso en oninit me muestra el contenido pero no pagina

Comment: Bueno usé tu mismo codigo_fuente y lo adapté a mi proyecto y funciona perfectamente, tal vez el error podria venir del backend. Actualizé mi respuesta puedes probar con ese fragmento de codigo. params lo cambié por paramMap y la obtencion del parametro +params.get('page');

Comment: con el metodo onchanges no me muestra el contenido ni la paginacion.. mi backend está bien lo he probado con postman

Comment: ya lo he solucionado el error estaba en <ul class="pagination">
   <li class="page-item">
     <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/pruebabook', prev_page]">&laquo;</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let num of number_pages">
      <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/pruebabook', num]" href="">{{ num }}</a>
   </li>

   <li class="page-item">
     <a class="page-link" [routerLink]="['/pruebabook', next_page]">&raquo;</a>
   </li>
 </ul> le estaba pasando mal el routerLink